# BMP180 ERROR read

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a project with an ESP8266 and a BMP 180
Following this code

The first read is everything okay ..but after just 214° celsius

Temperature = 22.70 Celsius

Pressure = 102686 Pascal

Temperature = 214.50 Celsius
Pressure = 235302 Pascal

Temperature = 214.50 Celsius
Pressure = 235302 Pascal

```
 #include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>

Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Wire.begin (4, 5);
  if (!bmp.begin()) 
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find BMP180 or BMP085 sensor at 0x77");
    while (1) {}
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(bmp.readTemperature());
  Serial.println(" Celsius");

  Serial.print("Pressure = ");
  Serial.print(bmp.readPressure());
  Serial.println(" Pascal");


  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? you make it sound like we would somehow know what you expect to see .... what is your question? you have not asked one.

Comment: Maybe the maximum operating temperature of 80 Celsius stated in the datasheet to be the reason .? You're a bit above that.